# How to deal with DISPLAY=:0.0

Tags: linux, bash, shell, configuration, x11

My X program sometimes must be started from console, but by default on Ubuntu the DISPLAY env var is not set. Is it correct to include `DISPLAY=:0.0 startmyapp` in the startup script, or how to deal with it otherwise? Who and when and how is responsible for setting this display variable properly? Why the environment is not out of the box ready for this once you install X or the desktop that includes X?

Comment: The shell cannot assume that your display is always `localhost:0.0` (which is what :0.0 amounts to), as your actual display may be elsewhere (even on another IP address altogether).
You could put a definition of $DISPLAY somewhere at the start of your process, but you may want to check that $DISPLAY isn't defined already.

Answer (score 0):

The `DISPLAY` variable controls the X session that the application communicates with. There can be many (or none) of these available at any given moment. You can't just statically set this value and have it necessarily be correct.

It is set correctly inside an X session (through the environment) and you can set it manually outside of that to use that same session (but you have to know which session you want to use for that).

If you know that will always be your session and you know that will always be the session you want to use then yes, you can just set it in the services startup script. Otherwise you need to come up with some other way to figure out which `DISPLAY` value you need.